# Writing an article on a town, how can I make it into an interesting and worthy article? [from my world's equivalent of Wikipedia]

Tags: politics, geography, history

I am writing articles on the various villages, towns and cities in my world. This is from my world's equivalent of Wikipedia and the entire wiki is a WIP, and you are welcome to help contribute to it.

[This article on Bladgweston is one such example](http://magnabritain6.mwzip.com/wiki/Bladgeweston). Bladgweston is in [Universe 3](http://magnabritain6.mwzip.com/wiki/Magna_Britain:Universes) of my world [a larger United Kingdom, different geography, more counties]. All three universes linked to are mentioned on the wiki and being expanded.

I am developing this article and would appreciate any help. Please feel free to join the wiki and help if you would like to do so, I would appreciate it.

Any advice and guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to include some Chekhov's guns into the articles.

Comment: Um, one of two actions should take place here. Either this question should be moved to writers.se for the question in your title, or it should be moved to the meta site for the actual text of the "question".

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the purpose of your worldbuilding. Are you doing it for a novel or a similar setting where **you** are telling a story, or are you doing it for a game where **the players** are supposed to understand the world and derive vital clues?

You have to present a simple and consistent world to your players if you want them to draw conclusions. Reality is unrealistic, as the proverb goes, and with lots of random detail to clutter the picture. There is a reason why crime scene investigators don't solve cases in 40 minutes (less credits).

Comment: I am doing it for a partially in-story reason, and partially roleplaying online ones, if that helps.

Comment: @magnabritain1986, then it should be simple. If you "plant" clues in the background reading, make sure that there are several ways to get the same information and that there is no dead end if the players don't "collect the plot coupon" ....

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the location. I'd start by looking at Wikipedia articles for bizarre or depressing towns and build on the general concepts and patterns.

Here's some things that make any article interesting, I've given sample articles for each:

- Crime sprees "bonus points for making the crime bizarre" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Brennan_Crutchley
- Unusual inhabitants https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibsonton,_Florida
- Local landmarks that are well known, such as famous monuments, concentration camps, or geographical landmarks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%C5%9Bwi%C4%99cim
- Anything involving death or sex or inappropriate things https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conisbrough https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butt_Hole_Road